# Get renamed column from database view without "update model from database..."?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there any way if we use database first approach, that we can get the renamed column name (from a view) without the need of right clicking inside edmx and selecting "update model from database..."?

**Example**

We have following example view in mssql:

```
SELECT 'My first column' column1, 'My second column' column2, 'My third column' column3
```

this creates following output in my web-application:

[image]

In the edmx, it looks like that:

[image]

The call already is dynamic, so no dto class behind as I want it dynamic:

[image]

**Question**

How can one change the upper view for example to the following:

```
SELECT 'My first column' columnNameChanged1, 'My second column' secondColumn, 'My third column' thridOneYeah
```

So the output in the application is correct (new column names applied) and there is no error message from entity framework, which states, that there is no defined "column1" and all this *WITHOUT the need to "update model from database..."* in visual studio. I want it as dynamic as possible.

So any changes on the database to the view (column name) should reflect on the web-page without the need of changing / updating the code and opening visual studio at all. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you connect to the DB using any DB tool like Mangement Studio? You can simply edit or even drop and (re)create the view using plain SQL

Comment: of course I have access to the DB. This is what I want. If I change the view from Management Studio, then it should give the correct output in the application without touching the code. But if we change the view like in my example, then we get error message from, that "column1" was not found because the mapping was done for "column1"...

Comment: If there's a mapping in code so you need to honor it. Maybe what do you want is a dynamic way to read any number of unnamed columns but you will retrieve a mass of data. Now imagine you got a table with 3 varchar(14) columns. How do you know what the first column means? Positional column? I remember doins something like that with dommel/mapper but I don't know if it's possible to do with EF. Anyway EF is "strong typed" meaning you must do the map column to property thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came to conclusion that it is probably not possible to do what I wanted. I am calling now Stored Procedures from code (don't need to map them) which return the same result and this works fine and dynamic too.